# Inverse of a complex active record query

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have a complex active record query here:

```
House.includes(:bookings).where("(bookings.status = ? AND bookings.check_in <= ? AND bookings.check_out >= ?) 
  OR (bookings.status = ? AND bookings.check_in <= ? AND bookings.check_out >= ?)", 
  'booked', check_dates[:check_out_date], check_dates[:check_in_date], 
  'blocked', check_dates[:check_out_date], check_dates[:check_in_date]).references(:bookings).uniq
```

I want to get the rest of the `House` that not in this query.
But `includes` can't take `not` query.

Comment: Don't know why my question got down vote without any comment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, there is an easy way an hard way.

Two ways to solve that:

First:

```
ids = House.includes(:bookings).where("(bookings.status = ? AND bookings.check_in <= ? AND bookings.check_out >= ?) 
  OR (bookings.status = ? AND bookings.check_in <= ? AND bookings.check_out >= ?)", 
  'booked', check_dates[:check_out_date], check_dates[:check_in_date], 
  'blocked', check_dates[:check_out_date], check_dates[:check_in_date]).references(:bookings).uniq.ids
result = House.where.now(id: ids)
```

Second:

```
House.includes(:bookings).where("NOT( (bookings.status = ? AND bookings.check_in <= ? AND bookings.check_out >= ?) 
  OR (bookings.status = ? AND bookings.check_in <= ? AND bookings.check_out >= ?) )", 
  'booked', check_dates[:check_out_date], check_dates[:check_in_date], 
  'blocked', check_dates[:check_out_date], check_dates[:check_in_date]).references(:bookings).uniq
```

Comment: Thanks! Will the first one have more mysql queries than the second one?

Comment: Yes, second one is better. First one will transfer IDs of all record from DB to Rails, and then to DB again.

Comment: Thank you again for the replies!